# Use jQuery to automatically add arrows to all parent menus

Tags: jquery

I have simple unordered list menu. Code is below or you can grab it from [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klikerko/3k8vv/):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Second - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second - 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second - 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Aaa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bbb</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ccc</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to use jQuery to add this markup `<span class="arrow"></span>` to all menus containing child menus, all parent menus. In this case this code should be added just after **Second** and **Second - 2** menu link, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a><span class="arrow"></span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Second - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second - 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second - 3</a><span class="arrow"></span>
                <ul>...........
```

Any suggestions what is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('li > ul').before('<span class="arrow"></span>');
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting solution will be this short. I like how's your brain wired. Thanks PaulPRO!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').has('ul').children('a').append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
```

Comment: Hi Christopher, your code works great but I chose the one just a little bit shorter. Thanks!